# Hyperledger fabric parent-CA certificate renewal

Tags: ssl-certificate, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca, ibm-blockchain, azure-blockchain-workbench

Using BAF, we have setup a hyperledger fabric network in kubernetes. It has 15 channels, 31 orgs ( each org has 1 peer) and 5 orderers. It's age is now nearly 1 year. Now all the certificates are going expire. Can anyone please suggest how to resolve this and how to renew parent cert/ peer's cert/ tls cert/ users cert? Is there any to renew all the certs?

Answer (score -1):

Renewing certificates is a tedious task and requires an extra care.

You can get a reference for you BAF setup by following this informative blog [here](https://medium.com/coinmonks/certification-rotation-in-hyperledger-fabric-c9eb5fc68dec).